# pick keys with equal values and create a new list from them

Tags: java

I have a following Map:

```
public Map<Player, Integer> results = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

and I want to create a new List of Players that have the same Integer value (highestScore) in the results map.

I calculate highestScore - works OK:

```
Optional<Integer> highestScore = scoreResultsSorted.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst();
```

I initialized `public List<Player> tiePlayers = new ArrayList<>();`

And my approaches are:

1)

```
    for (Map.Entry<Player, Integer> entry : results.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(highestScore)) {
            tiePlayers.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

2. `tiePlayers = (List<Player>) results.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(highestScore)).map(Map.Entry::getKey);`

The first one returns empty array [], the second one returns "java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3 cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3 and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')".

The second exception I dont really get. In the first I cannot find the reason its empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value from the `Optional` to compare it.

Thus, the first solution should be:

```java
if (entry.getValue().equals(highestScore.get()))
```

The same applies to the solution with streams. In addition, do not cast to `List`; you should be using `Collectors.toList()`.

```
results.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(highestScore.get()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```